# How to create a Typescript Array-like structure with a typed index?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In a typescript declaration file (directions.d.ts), I have the following code so far:

```
interface DIRECTION {}
declare const TOP: DIRECTION;
declare const TOP_RIGHT: DIRECTION;
declare const RIGHT: DIRECTION;
declare const BOTTOM_RIGHT: DIRECTION;
declare const BOTTOM: DIRECTION;
declare const BOTTOM_LEFT: DIRECTION;
declare const LEFT: DIRECTION;
declare const TOP_LEFT: DIRECTION;

declare const MOVE_COST:{
    [index: DIRECTION]: number
}
```

My goal is to be able to be able to use MOVE_COST in a type sensitive way (e.g.)

```
console.log(MOVE_COST[TOP]) // This is valid.
console.log(MOVE_COST[BOTTOM]) // This is valid.
console.log(MOVE_COST[3]) // This should be an error.
```

Now, in the end, these constants (e.g. TOP, BOTTOM, etc.) all are defined as integers in the execution environment, so it is perfectly valid to index the MOVE_COST array with them.

However, typescript always throws

```
error TS1023: An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'.
```

How should I declare `MOVE_COST` so that it can be accessed the way I want it to be?

Answer (score 2):

The following typescript code should be the closest possible way to do what you want, since an index signature parameter must be a string or number.

[Link to CodePen Sample](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NXwMoN)

```
enum Direction {
    TOP = "top",
    TOP_RIGHT= "top_right",
    RIGHT= "right",
    BOTTOM_RIGHT= "bottom_right",
    BOTTOM= "bottom",
    BOTTOM_LEFT= "bottom_left",
    LEFT= "left",
    TOP_LEFT= "top_left"
}

var values: {[id in Direction]: string; } = {};
values[Direction.TOP] = "test";

let button = document.createElement('button');
button.textContent = "Test";

button.onclick = function() {
    alert(values[Direction.TOP]);
}

document.body.appendChild(button);
```